# Why does Python complain about reference before assignment when increasing variables in a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

Why does Python complain about `chrome` being referenced before assignment? It does not complain about the dictionary. This is with Python 2.5 if it makes a difference.

```
def f():
  google['browser'] = 'chrome'
  chrome += 1

google = dict()
chrome = 1
f()
```

I can make it work with `global chrome` of course, but I'd like to know why Python does't consider the variable to be assigned. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's out of scope: [read here](http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2006/07/python-functions-assignments-and-scope.html)

Answer (score 5):

In the statement

```
chrome += 1
```

and it has not been created yet. 
The variables are created the first time they are assigned. In this case, when python sees the code incrementing 'chrome', it doesn't see this variable at all.

Try rearranging your code as

```
chrome = 1

def f():
  global chrome
  google['browser'] = 'chrome'
  chrome += 1

google = dict()
f()
```

Comment: @irrelephant: Thanks. A typo missed out the global keyword! corrected.

Comment: Thanks. Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.