# Variable scoping error during recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion, scope

The following code recursively processes a list of dictionaries into a tree while building an HTML output string. I'm getting a scope access error when trying to access the `output` string variable from within the recursing function. However, it has no problem accessing the `nodes` list object in the same scope- and in fact the function worked fine before I added the `output` var. What's the deal here?

Sample:
http://ideone.com/Kg8ti

```
nodes = [ 
{ 'id':1, 'parent_id':None, 'name':'a' },
{ 'id':2, 'parent_id':None, 'name':'b' },
{ 'id':3, 'parent_id':2, 'name':'c' },
{ 'id':4, 'parent_id':2, 'name':'d' },
{ 'id':5, 'parent_id':4, 'name':'e' },
{ 'id':6, 'parent_id':None, 'name':'f' }
]

output = ''

def build_node(node):
    output += '<li><a>'+node['name']+'</a>'
    subnodes = [subnode for subnode in nodes if subnode['parent_id'] == node['id']]
    if len(subnodes) > 0 : 
        output += '<ul>'
        [build_node(subnode) for subnode in subnodes]
        output += '</ul>'
    output += '</li>'
    return node

output += '<ul>'
node_tree = [build_node(node) for node in nodes if node['parent_id'] == None]
output += '</ul>'   

import pprint
pprint.pprint(node_tree)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 23, in <module>
    node_tree = [build_node(node) for node in nodes if node['parent_id'] == None]
  File "prog.py", line 13, in build_node
    output += '<li><a>'+node['name']+'</a>'
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030968/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error stems from this:

```
output = ''
def add(s):
    output = output + s
```

which is equivalent to `output+=s`. The two `output`-s in the expanded form refer to different scopes. The assignment sets a local variable while the expression on the right references a global (because local isn't set yet).

Python detects such conflicts and throws an error.

Others have suggested using `global` to let Python know both `output`-s refer to the global scope but since you're concatenating strings here, there's an even better idiom used for this task in Python:

```
output_list = []
def add(s):
    output_list.append(s)
# ...
output = ''.join(output_list)
```

Here you're not setting a variable in the function so there's no need for `global`. Strings from all calls are added to a list and finally joined using `''` (empty string) as separator. This is much faster than adding strings using `+=` because strings in Python are immutable so every time you add two strings, Python has to create a new string. This introduces a lot of memory copying.

Comment: For some supporting info on why this works, take a peak at [Python Functions: Assignments And Scope](http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2006/07/python-functions-assignments-and-scope.html)

Comment: Had a look at that page. Simply put, `n[0]=n[0]+1` isn't creating a local variable. It more or less expands to `n.__setitem__(0, n.__getitem__(0)+1)` which shows that `n` is only referenced, never assigned to, much like `output_list.append()` in my code.

Comment: Exactly- it's the whole bare-name referencing he's talking about (Yak I know you get it, the link was for others who might want some extra explanation.) Good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
def build_node(node):
    global output
    # proceed as before
```

Comment: How come `nodes` doesn't need global?

Comment: `nodes` isn't being assigned to in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can use a `global` declaration, it would be much clearer to pass `output` as a parameter.

[Global variables are considered to bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) and where there are good methods to avoid using them you should avail yourself of those methods.

Comment: David- thanks- but can you explain why I am able to access the `nodes` object without passing it?

Comment: Because you are reading from it and not writing to it. If you assign to a global you have to tell the interpreter whether or not the name is a global or a local.

Comment: David- This won't work. When I pass output as a parameter, it is not accessible by the outer functions- in your code example the output string never gets built up.

Comment: This would not work. Strings in Python are immutable: you cannot pass a string to a function and have the function changing the string.

Comment: @6502 Drat! The basic principle is correct, but the extra return variable gets in the way here.